# Pagination in Php SQLITE

Tags: php, html, sql, sqlite, pagination

I'm quite new to PHP. I'm playing around with connecting to a `sqlite` database and I've done that successfully. For some reason my pagination is not working.

The value of `$page` won't go beyond 2. Can someone help me out, I'm sure its probably a simple mistake. (So currently it does change from the first page to the next.

[image: A screenshot of the database (as it is currently)]

```
    <?php
  try
  {
    //open the database
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:client.db');

    //create the database
    $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Client (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, first_name VARCHAR(50), last_name VARCHAR(50), email VARCHAR(50), gender VARCHAR(50))");

$page = 1;
if(!empty($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if(false === $page) {
        $page = 1;
    }
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //something posted

    if (isset($_POST['Previous'])) {
        print 'current value of $page = ' . $page;
        print "<br>";
        if($page <= 0) {
          $page = 1;
        }else {
          $page = $page - 1;
        }
    } else if(isset($_POST['Next'])) {
        print 'current value of $page = ' . $page;
        print "<br>";
        $page = $page + 1;
    }
}





// set the number of items to display per page
$limit = 10;

// build query
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
if($offset <= 0) {
  $offset = 0;
}
print '$page = ' . $page;
print "<br>";
print '$offset = ' . $offset;
    //now output the data to a simple html table...
    print "<table border=1>";
    print "<tr><td>Id</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Gender</td></tr>";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Client LIMIT " . $offset . "," . $limit;

    $result = $db->query($sql);
    //$rows = count($result);
    //print $rows;
    //checks if table has data
    //$count = $result->fetchColumn();

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
      print "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['first_name']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['last_name']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['gender']."</td></tr>";
    }


  print "</table>";
  print "<br>";
  //print "<button type=\"button\" name=\"button\"><< Previous </button>";
  //print "<button type=\"button\" name=\"button\">Next >></button>";
  print "<form class=\"\" action=\"\" method=\"post\">";
  print  "<button type=\"submit\" name=\"Previous\">Previous</button>";
  print  "<br><br><button type=\"submit\" name=\"Next\">Next</button>";
  print "</form>";

    // close the database connection
    $db = NULL;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

Comment: You are sending the `$page` variable as a parameter of the form action URL? It must be on it as that is where you expect to find it next time the form is sent. i.e. `$_GET['page]` is set from the URL query parameters.

Comment: Hi Ryan , Thanks for your reply. I am such a newbie to PHP, that I would not know how to do that. I’m literally just starting out, but have experience in other programming languages, any advice or help would be appreciated

Comment: `<form class=\"\" action=\"\"?page=\"42\"` to pass the page number 42 to the PHP script and have it appear as the `$_GET['page'];` and be equal to 42.  maybe interesting? tutorial: http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for that, but the page number is dependent on whether the user clicked next or previous e.g [Click Next => page= page + 1] or [Click Previous => page= page - 1] and thanks for the tutorial link :-)

Comment: I know that the page number is held in $page number. I was expecting you to,,, nevermind :) do: `'<form class="" action=?page="'. $page ,'"';` Or something very like that.

Comment: hey ryan Thanks for the info. is there any way I can mark your answers as the accepted solution. You deserve the credit. It worked out. Im still learning php though as i go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All credit goes to Ryan-Vincent for helping me solve this.

Basically, I had everything working, but had the incorrect attribute for the form action.

This is the only thing I changed and it worked fine (this is the opening form tag in html, notice the page url parameter gets its value from the php page variable.

```
  print "<form class=\"\" action=\"?page=$page \" method=\"POST\">";
```

Hope this helps other php newbies.